# Как правильно писать/говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно писать: "дверь на сигнализации" или "дверь под сигнализацией"?

Answer (score 1):

**СИГНАЛИЗАЦИЯ**, 3. Система автоматизированной охраны с устройством для подачи звуковых сигналов. Установить, провести, включить, отключить сигнализацию.  **Поставить, взять квартиру на сигнализацию.** Автомобиль с сигнализацией.

Используются **оба выражения**, но более правильным мне кажется: ***поставить на сигнализацию — дверь на сигнализации.*** Форма ***под сигнализацией*** повторяет вариант ***под охраной***.

Примеры

Ну и что, что **всё на сигнализации**!  [Михаил Шишкин, 2005]

Какая-нибудь  забегаловка давно стоит **на сигнализации** в областном УВД, а кабинет комдива всего лишь на решетке.  [Варвара Синицына.  (2002)]

― На НВП военрук ведет нас ― четверых пацанов ― в свою каморку, которая **под сигнализацией** и закрывается сначала решеткой, потом железной дверью.  [Владимир Козлов. Гопники (2002)]

Учтите, все находится **под сигнализацией**!  [Дмитрий Емец.  (2002)]

Comment: Удивительно много книжных примеров с "под сигнализацией(-ю)". Возможно, на выбор предлога подсознательно влияет выражение "(объект) _под защитой_ сигнализации": в полной формулировке оно звучит излишне формально.

Answer (score 1):

На практике используются *оба* варианта (несмотря на скудную статистику "Корпуса", находится много книжных примеров того и другого). Вероятно, разные предлоги соответствуют (или должны соответствовать - не все люди разборчивы) двум разным аспектам ссылки на сигнализацию (организационному и техническому).

> У меня дверь **на** сигнализации.

Это может означать факт постановки **на обслуживание** с использованием **сигнализации**, если коротко, "постановки **на** сигнализацию" (служащие охраны явятся при её срабатывании).

> Не пытайся сразу дверь ломать: она сейчас **под** сигнализацией!

Здесь речь идёт о нахождении **под** (технической) **защитой сигнализации**; в этом примере *под сигнализацией* (вместо формального *под защитой сигнализации*) акцентирует текущее *включённое состояние* средств сигнализации, безотносительно оформленной где-то постановки ***на*** обслуживание.